# finding duplicates in a string at python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def find_duplicate():
    x =input("Enter a word = ")
    for char in x :
        counts=x.count(char)
        while counts > 1:
            return print(char,counts)
```

I've got small problem in there i want to find all duplicates in string but this program give me only one duplicate ex: aassdd is my input function gave me only a : 2 but it need to be in that form a : 2 s : 2 d : 2 thanks for your answers.

Comment: You immediately `return`...

Comment: You are looking for `collections.Counter`

Comment: Because when you *return* the function stops executing... Also, why are you returning the result of a call to `print`? This will always return `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` is a keyword that works more or less as *immediately exit this function (and optionally carry some output with you)*. You thus need to remove the `return` statement:

```
def find_duplicate():
    x =input("Enter a word = ")
    for char in x :
        counts=x.count(char)
        print(char,counts)
```

Furthermore you also have to remove the `while` loop (or update the counter if you want to `print` multiple times), otherwise you will get stuck in an infinite loop since `count` is not updated and the test will thus always succeed.

Mind however that in this case `a` will be printed multiple times (in this case two) if it is found multiple times in the string. You can solve this issue by first constructing a `set` of the characters in the string and iterate over this set:

```
def find_duplicate():
    x =input("Enter a word = ")
    for char in set(x):
        counts=x.count(char)
        print(char,counts)
```

Finally it is better to make a separation between *functions that calculate* and *functions that do I/O* (for instance `print`). So you better make a function that returns a dictionary with the counts, and one that prints that dictionary. You can generate a dictionary like:

```
def find_duplicate(x):
    result = {}
    for char in set(x):
        result[char]=x.count(char)
    return result
```

And a calling function:

```
def do_find_duplicates(x):
    x =input("Enter a word = ")
    for key,val in find_duplicate(x).items():
        print(key,val)
```

And now the best part is: you actually do not need to write the `find_duplicate` function: there is a utility class for that: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def do_find_duplicates(x):
    x =input("Enter a word = ")
    for key,val in Counter(x).items():
        print(key,val)
```

Comment: Of course, this `while` loop will never terminate in the case where `counts` > 1.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: good point. Hadn't thaken that into account. Will rewrite my answer.

Comment: Counter is only for single characters; is there a way to do the same but make it get duplicates for sequances of 3 charater and more ?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
 def find_duplicate():
    x = input("Enter a word = ")
    for char in set(x):
        counts = x.count(char)
        while counts > 1:
            print(char, ":", counts, end=' ')
            break
find_duplicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_duplicate():
    x = input("Enter a word = ")
    dup_letters = []
    dup_num = []

    for char in x:
        if char not in dup_letters and x.count(char) > 1:
            dup_letters.append(char)
            dup_num.append(x.count(char))

    return zip(dup_letters, dup_num)

dup = find_duplicate()

for i in dup:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because this is fun, a solution that leverages the built-ins to avoid writing any more custom code than absolutely needed:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

# To let you count characters while preserving order of first appearance
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): pass

def find_duplicate(word):
    return [(ch, cnt) for ch, cnt in OrderedCounter(word).items() if cnt > 1]
```

It's likely more efficient (it doesn't recount each character over and over), only reports each character once, and uses arguments and return values instead of `input` and `print`, so it's more versatile (your `main` method can prompt for `input` and `print` output if it chooses).

Usage is simple (and thanks to `OrderedCounter`, it preserves order of first appearance in the original string too):

```
>>> find_duplicate('aaacfdedbfrf')
[('a', 3), ('f', 3), ('d', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This version should be fast as I am not using any library or more than one cycle, do you have any faster options?

```py
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

some_string = 'Laptop' * 99999

ans_dict = {}

for i in some_string:
  if i in ans_dict:
    ans_dict[i] += 1
  else:
    ans_dict[i] = 1

print(ans_dict)

end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(end_time - start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_duplicate():
x = input("Enter a word = ")
y = ""
check = ""
for char in x:
    if x.count(char) > 1 and char not in y and char != check:
        y += (char + ":" + str(x.count(char)) + " ")
        check = char
return y.strip()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).